# C# Core 2.0 - get data from one model based on data in another model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I am using .NET Core 2.0

I do have 2 tables:

```
Movies
ID | Name | AuthorId
----------------------
1  | AAAA | 1
2  | BBBB | 1
3  | CCCC | 1
4  | DDDD | 2

Reviews
ID | FilmId | AuthorId | SomeText
------------------------------------
1  | 1        | 1        | this is horror
2  | 1        | 2        | this is comendy
3  | 3        | 1        | it may be horror
4  | 3        | 2        | it is definitely comedy, not horror
```

My Models are:

```
class Movie {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

class Review {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public int FilmId  { get; set; }
    public Movie Film { get; set; }
}
```

My Context is:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Review> Review { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().HasMany(m => m.Reviews).WithOne(r => r.Film);
        }
    }
```

**Now I want to make such query:**

> SELECT * FROM Movies m JOIN Reviews r ON (m.ID == r.FilmId) WHERE
>   m.AuthorId = 1 AND (r.AuthorID = 3 OR r.SomeText LIKE '%definitely%');

The expected result should be **CCCC**.

Currently I do have:

```
List<Movie> movies = _context.Movie.Include(m => m.Reviews.Select(r => r.AuthorId == 3 || r.SomeText.Contains("definitely"))).ToList();
```

**Howto express above query with this notation?**

However I do get:

> InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'm => {from Review
>   r in m.Reviews select (([r].AuthorId == __user_ID_0) OrElse
>   [r].SomeText.Contains("definitely"))}' is not valid. The expression
>   should represent a property access: 'r => r.MyProperty'. For more
>   information on including related data, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

I have read this article but it gave me nothing.

Comment: `Where`, not `Select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this linq query returns the correct result (since I cannot test it)

```
List<Movie> movies = _context.Movie.where(m => m.AuthorId == 1 && m.Reviews.Any(r => 
r.AuthorId == 3 ||  r.SomeText.Contains("definitely"))).ToList();
```